# Having a tests sub-package without nose pre-importing your package

Tags: python, nose

I have the following directory structure

```
package
    __init__.py
    module1
        model1.py
    tests
        __init__.py
        common.py
        test_module1
            test_model1.py
```

I need to:

1. Have a place to put common 'helpers' for tests, such as shared data. I'm currently using `common.py`. I *think* this necessitates having an `__init__` in the `tests` path, so test files can import common.
2. Not import `package` before running tests, because I need to test that the configs load correctly (and so need to make changes to environment variables before importing `package` and test that flows through to its configs). Nosetests seems to *insist* on importing `package` if `tests` is a package (i.e. if there's an `__init__` in tests).

Is there a way of doing this? Or should I be changing my setup? I could have `common` in `package` directly, although that seems awkward.

A question that touches on this issue: [Python imports for tests using nose - what is best practice for imports of modules above current package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670275/python-imports-for-tests-using-nose-what-is-best-practice-for-imports-of-modul)

Comment: What's wrong with putting the `__init__.py`,  Regardless of where you put your `common.py` your tests directory needs to have `__init__.py` otherwise nose will not be able to discover tests from `tests` directory