# Relative vs. Absolute imports for Flask and nose

Tags: python-3.x, flask, nose

I have a Flask app that has the following directory structure:

```
    ├── README.md
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── constants.py
    ├── businesspackage
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── detection
    │   ├── flagging_spec.txt
    │   └── tests
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── run.py
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        └── test_api.py
```

Within `detection`'s `__init__.py`, I have imported my necessary classes, so that I can import the classes from that top-level module, rather than needing to give the full path to each of the `.py` files inside of the module.

I am attempting to import some classes from `detection` from inside `run.py`, but am coming across the following error: when I try to run my Flask application from the top-level directory using `python3 run.py`:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "run.py", line 9, in <module>
        from .businesspackage.detection import AdsDetection
    SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

After reading some other questions on here, it suggested that I change from a relative import to an absolute import. However, if I try the following import in `run.py`:

```
    from businesspackage.detection import AdsDetection
```

Then I can run my Flask server without the import error, however, my imports break for the nose test runner. I am running the tests using the `nosetests` command, with nose 1.3.7 . How can I define my imports so that they work for both the Flask server, and for my nosetests?

Edit:

`businesspackage.__init__.py` is the following:

```
    from .business_detection import BusinessDetector
```

Comment: Can you add what your businesspackage.__init__.py looks like?

Comment: @AllieFitter sure, went ahead and added it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

So for some weird reason, I managed to get the absolute imports to work after deleting the `__init__.py` file in the base level directory: i.e. my directory structure looks like follows:

```
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── constants.py
├── businesspackage
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── detection
│   ├── flagging_spec.txt
│   └── tests
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    └── test_api.py
```

I figured I should give it a try after seeing one of the answers on here: [Python imports for tests using nose - what is best practice for imports of modules above current package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670275/python-imports-for-tests-using-nose-what-is-best-practice-for-imports-of-modul) . So now, all of my package is using absolute imports.