# Python imports for testing modules with additional dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, python-import

I want to have my tests in a separate folder from my package code, such that from the top level directory of my project I can run `python sample/run.py` or `python tests/test_run.py`, and have both of them resolve all the imports properly.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
sample/
   __init__.py
   helper.py
   run.py
tests/
   context.py
   test_run.py
```

I know there are supposedly many ways to achieve this, as discussed here: [Python imports for tests using nose - what is best practice for imports of modules above current package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670275/python-imports-for-tests-using-nose-what-is-best-practice-for-imports-of-modul)

However, when I try to run `python tests/test_run.py`, I get a *ModuleNotFoundError* for 'helper', because 'sample/run.py' imports 'sample/helper.py'.

In particular, I am trying to follow the convention (suggested in the [Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#test-suite)) of explicitly modifying the path using:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

As a result, I have a blank `sample/__init__.py`, along with the following code files.

sample/run.py:

```
from helper import helper_fn
def run():
    helper_fn(5)
    return 'foo'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

sample/helper.py:

```
def helper_fn(N):
    print(list(range(N)))
```

tests/context.py:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import sample
```

tests/test_run.py:

```
from context import sample
from sample import run

assert run.run() == 'foo'
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why is Python unable to find the 'helper' module?
2. How do I fix things so that I can run *both* `sample/run.py` and `tests/test_run.py` from the top-level directory?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  The way that imports are looked up is slightly different in both.

Comment: Python 3, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

To make both `sample/run.py` and `tests/test_run.py` work, you should add the path of `sample` directory into python path. So, your `tests/context.py` should be

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../sample')))


import sample
```

This change will let Python know the path of `helper` module.

---

<s>`sample/run.py` should be:</s>

```
  from .helper import helper_fn
  def run():
     helper_fn(5)
     return 'foo'
  if __name__ == '__main__':
     run()
```

Implicit relative imports within packages are not available in Python 3. Please check below:

> The import system has been updated to fully implement the second phase of PEP 302. There is no longer any implicit import machinery - the full import system is exposed through sys.meta_path. In addition, native namespace package support has been implemented (see PEP 420). [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

This [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) might be helpful to understand Intra-Package-References.

Comment: This fixes the import error when running `tests/test_run.py`, but it leads to `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.helper'; '__main__' is not a package` when running `sample/run.py`.

Comment: The linked documentation says it's not possible to use relative imports in a module intended for use as the main module, so I tried abstracting the `if __name__ == 'main': run()` into a new file called `sample/main.py` (along with `from run import run`). When using the relative import suggested above (`from .helper ...`), it works for `tests/test_run.py` and fails for `sample/main.py`. With the original import (`from helper ...`), it works for `sample/main.py` but not `tests/test_run.py`.

Comment: The relative import suggested above *does* work if you run `python -m sample.run`, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23542795/. I still find this pretty unsatisfying though, since now there are two ways you need to invoke python, depending on whether it's a test script or a project script. Is there any way where I can still call both scripts as specified at the beginning of the question?

Comment: @camall3n I edited my solution. This change will make both codes work and can answer your first question.

Comment: This still seems kind of ugly, but I'll admit that it does what I asked for. I'm accepting this answer unless someone can think of a cleaner solution.