# Import package from subfolder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

(I appreciate there are many similar questions on StackOverflow already, but none seemed to help me.)

I have the following structure:

```
code/
  foo/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar/
      __init__.py
      bar.py
```

I want to be able to import `foo` as a package in `bar.py` without messing with `sys`.

This is my `foo.py`:

```
hello = 'Hello, world!'
```

This is my `bar.py`:

```
import foo

print(foo.hello)
```

But if I execute `python foo/bar/bar.py` I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

Of all things, the one that's driving me crazy the most is that if I add the following snippet on top of `bar.py`:

```
import pkgutil

search_path = ['.']
all_modules = [x[1] for x in pkgutil.iter_modules(path=search_path)]
print(all_modules)
```

Then I actually get `foo` as an available module (still failing), here:

```
['foo']
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Import python package from another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234609/how-to-import-python-package-from-another-directory)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It does not, they use PYTHONPATH (sys) which I don't want to, plus that thread's OP is trying to import a sibling module, whilst I want to import the current package.

Comment: Look at the last approach, it doesn't use `sys` and it's pretty much the same principle.