# No module named <modulename> when importing from another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below folder structure for my python project:

```
./SampleA/
   __init__.py
   company.py
./SampleB/
   __init__.py
   check.py
```

Now i am trying to import `company.py` module in my `check.py` module using the below command:

```
from SampleA import company
```

when i run the file i get the below error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SampleA'
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: @rdas - when i append the path , the vscode editor moves the all the import files to the top and sys.path.append is only after import commands. so import company could not import the module.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61235118/8873120) answer your question?

Comment: @RMPR - no it does not work for me. sys.path.append line of code comes after the import statement. So import happens before the path added to the path.

Comment: There's no mention to `sys.path.append` in the answer I linked

Answer (score 0):

You're Trying to Import sibling module and not child module.
Say You're Folder structure is something like

```
-SampleB
 - __init__
 - check
 - SampleA
```

Then it will work.
- Right way to import sibling packages follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)