# A Value Error As "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror

My Project looks like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3ocI.jpg

how do I import the views.py in the pages app onto urls.py file of the trydjango app?

when I do :

```
from ..pages import views
```

gives

```
 ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package.
```

when i do:

```
import pages.views
```

it says no module pages as hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Import python package from another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234609/how-to-import-python-package-from-another-directory)

Comment: ```from ..pages import views``` pages isn't a module, it is a folder

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur how do i got the pages folder my dude . any idea?

Comment: @RMPR any idea where i should add the ```import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
``` in my file . i tried adding it to the urls.py file did nothing . also after using ``` import pages.views```

Comment: Have you checked @RMPR 's comment? That is the answer

Comment: @AbhinavMathur yea i looked at it . it says add parent directory to the ```PYTHONPATH```  in the first answer. ive been searching what this is.

Comment: ```sys.path.insert('..')``` is the same thing

Comment: @AbhinavMathur dude where shoud i write this bit of code ? in my settings.py or the file from which im importing.

Comment: The file where you're trying to import something

Comment: @AbhinavMathur dude nothing happened didnt make a difference.