# __init__.py in project folder breaks nose tests

Tags: python, testing, package, nose

**project tree:**

```
.
|-- bar.py
`-- test
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- test_bar.py
```

**bar.py:**

```
def dumb_true():
    return True
```

**tests/test_bar.py:**

```
import bar

def test_bar_true():
        assert bar.dumb_true()
```

I can run `nosetests` from inside the project or its test directory. If I add an empty `__init__.py` to the project folder, however, I can no longer run `nosetests` from inside the test directory, which doesn't make any sense to me.

```
.
|-- bar.py
|-- __init__.py  <-- new, empty file, ruining everything
`-- test
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- test_bar.py
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here?

I've read extensively on this topic - through nose documentation/man pages and all over the internet; but it looks very confusing to me how this all resolves!

Comment: what command are you using to run nose? Also, it might be more helpful to use absolute imports. If the directory that bar.py located in also named bar ?

Comment: Yeah, I know about absolute imports, but I don't like the leaves knowing the names of the branches they're inside of. I'm developing, so names are a bit liquid, so the name of the folder these things are in isn't reliable. I'm just running fairly stock `nosetests` calls.

Comment: Absolute imports are more accepted as standard practice in the python community than relative ones. Are you adding arguments to nosetests to specify the path of the tests? If so what path are you specifying?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073259/python-nose-import-error/3073368#3073368).

> You've got an `__init__.py` in your top level directory. That makes it a
>   package. If you remove it, your nosetests should work.
>
> If you don't remove it, you'll have to change your import to import
>   dir.foo, where dir is the name of your directory.