# Common init code for Nosetests

Tags: nose, nosetests

I want to have some initialization code shared across all my Nose tests. How would I do that?

(I don't want to have an [`__init__.py` in my `tests` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169447/init-py-in-project-folder-breaks-nose-tests). But maybe there is some `init.py` or so? I didn't found any documentation about that.)